# How to reference Custom WPF Control in generic.xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, namespaces, declaration, resourcedictionary

I'm trying to create a custom WPF control which inherits from the standard TextBlock like this:

```
public class DynamicDateTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    static DynamicDateTextBlock()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DynamicDateTextBlock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DynamicDateTextBlock)));
    }
}
```

The according generic.xaml looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DynamicDateTextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:DynamicDateTextBlock}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

If I put the control.cs in the root of my Solution Test everything works fine. 
But if I move it into a subfolder Test\Controls and change the namespaces accordingly suddenly the generic.xaml is giving compiling errors

> The name "DynamicDateTextBlock" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Test.Controls"

The cs namespace gets changed to `Test.Controls`

and in the xaml I try to use it like this: `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.Controls"`

Is there something else I must do?

Refactoring the control with Resharper to move it gives the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you move your `DynamicDateTextBlock` to `Controls` folder and after you've changed `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.Controls"` try to Rebuild and run your application even there are errors. The application should be started. All your actions are correct.

**Update:**
After changing the xaml `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.Controls"`, you should type again by your hands. I've typed by hand and there are no errors.

Comment: that's what I thought, but it is not compiling anymore after I moved the control giving: `There were build errors.` 

After trying to run, the error list shows one more:
`Cannot find the Style Property 'Template' on the type 'Test.Controls.DynamicDateTextBlock'. Line 5 Position 17.`

Comment: @Mikk please, see my updated answer. Feel free to ask any question.

Comment: that's strange, for me it is not working even by hand in a new, otherwise empty, solution. the autocomplete suggests exactly the same in intellisense.. but i can not build and run the result.

Comment: @Mikk try to reboot your PC and repeat typing by hand, not copying `xmlns`